# Laravel Views Subfolders routing

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

I have sub folders inside my view folder called

```
--views
 ---saledata(folder)
   ----saled.blade.php
 ---uploader(folder)
   ----datauploader.php
 ---home.blade.php
```

I want to route this saled.blade.php and datauploader.php files in web.php

I have tried with

```
route:: view('saledata','../saledata/saled');
route:: view('datauploader','datauploader');
```

in both the ways.but both shows 404 errors.

and this is the way I mentioned the url of the file in home.blade.php

```
 <a href="{{ url('saledata') }}" title="">
```

So please help  to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**if directly form the web file :**

```php
Route::get('saledata', function () {    
    return view('saledata.saled');
});
```

**if want to use in the controller:**

```php
public function index(Request $request) {
    return view('saledata.saled');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
//this code will be the laravel v8
//Route File code
Route::get('saledata',[yourControllerFile::class,'your_controller_method']);

//Controller file code
class yourControllerName extends controllers {
    public function your_controller_method() {
        return view('saledata');
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In route file:

```
Route::view('/saledata', 'saledata.saled')->name('saledata');
```

And in url:

```
<a href="{{ route('saledata') }}" title="">
```

Hope it will works.

Comment: Hello, could you solve the issue? Do you use linux or docker? If linux then go to the `/var/www/html/zynolo_datafeeder/` folder and type: `chmod -R 777 /storage` . Hopes it will solve the issue.